# Anyone have any idea which way from "30 01 00 00 40 03 00 00" bytes i can get values 19 and 104?

Tags: hex, byte

I have an object with coordinates 19, 104. Coordinates of this object represented by bytes "30 01 00 00 40 03 00 00"
If i replace first byte to 00, 19 turns into 16
Those 8 bytes is values of coordinates in some application, 4 byte per value, but it doesn't look like normal hex values... because for number 19 hex code is 13.
Maybe you know? There is a lot of weird things for me like big / little endian and etc...

Comment: Um... can you provide some context here? What is "16 O_o"? I've read this several times and can't figure out what you're asking. Do you think that "30 01 00 00" might represent one of the values and "40 03 00 00" might represent the other?

Comment: if i edit "30 01 00 00 40 03 00 00" in hex editor to "00 01 00 00 40 03 00 00" and then start application, the coordinate of object turns into 16 by X, but without edition it's 19. Yes... 4 bytes per value. That's what i think

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because each byte is being read in reverse (Big Endian), so `30` is interpreted as 3, and `01` is interpreted as 16. But the rest is being read ltr.

[What is Big Endian](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/B/big_endian.html)

[Endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)

Comment: ehm, I don't understand. In calculator i tried to convert hex values 01 30, 30 01 and 30 01 00 00 to decimal, but never got 19. The result is usually a big numbers

Comment: because each byte value is being added together without appropriate bit shifting

Comment: where you using calculator? if so, that is processing them in little Endian. It is also a bit of a mix, the bytes are listed as 4 separate entities together, so that is going left-to-right, but each one is in Big Endian, so is being treated as right-to-left

Comment: I am using windows calculator. If it possible, could you type the order in which i must enter those to calculator? I even tried now switch bytes at all like 01 -> 10, but still don't get 19.

Comment: `01` in little endian is `10`, which has an integer value of 16. `30` in little endian is `03`, which has an integer value of 3. Your code is not changing the numbers (which in your case would bit shift the first number by 0 bits, the second by 8 bits, the third by 16 bits and the fourth by 24 bits) before assembling them together, which will return a 32 bit number. It is just adding 16 and 3, thus, 19

Comment: oop, for the bit shifting, what I stated will be a little endian, if you want the four bytes in big endian, the first is 32 bits, and the fourth is 0 bits for shifting

Comment: Hope that helped, I found endianness to be a pain in my... end